# Loading main XIB makes app crash on iOS 3.0

Tags: ios, exception, xcode4.2, xib, ios-3.x

thank you for taking some time to read my question.
I have this app (In Cydia), which has around 10% of users with iOS 3.0, so I want to support them in my next update .

I tested it with actual devices running, iOS 4.0 and 5.0.1; it worked fine. But on iOS 3.0 it crashes with an exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0x4e, 0x49, 0x42, 0x41, 0x72, 0x63, 0x68, 0x69)
```

apparently when loading the main XIB, here's the backtrace of the exception:

```
0  0x30016588 in objc_exception_throw ()
1  0x30224026 in +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] ()
2  0x30223fc6 in +[NSException raise:format:] ()
3  0x305564b4 in -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:] ()
4  0x3094927c in -[UINib instantiateWithOptions:owner:loadingResourcesFromBundle:] ()
5  0x30949090 in -[NSBundle(NSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] ()
6  0x308f131c in -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile] ()
7  0x308f0f9c in -[UIApplication _runWithURL:sourceBundleID:] ()
8  0x309374b0 in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] ()
9  0x30936cf0 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
10 0x3093687c in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
11 0x3204696c in PurpleEventCallback ()
12 0x30254a76 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
13 0x3025416a in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
14 0x308f0354 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
15 0x308eea94 in UIApplicationMain ()
16 0x00003886 in main (argc=1, argv=0x2ffff74c)
```

I've read and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075161/ios-3-x-support-in-xcode-4) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868796/ios-and-unarchiving-xib-files). So I have all of my nibs with deployment version set to 3.0 and development to Interface Builder 3.0, still no luck.

Comment: Do you have an old XCode SDK? Have you tried opening the nib with InterfaceBuilder from such sdk?

Comment: Thanks @Peter, there's some progress I think, I followed your suggestion, fortunately I have access to Xcode 3.2, I compiled my project there, and after a few fixes, it works on the device with iOS 3.0, then I copied the exact same project to Xcode 4.2, and I Get the same error from before, I guess it's something about the way the new Xcode compiles the project.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think I've read somewhere that the xcode 4.2 nibs are backwards compatible only down to iOS 3.2. I'd try setting the minimal required target to 3.2 - or try to use nibs created with old sdk without recompiling them inside of XCode 4.2.

Comment: you're righ @Peter !! according to apple Docs: "iOS 3.2 supports loading unstripped nib files, but iOS releases prior to 3.2 do not. If you choose to build unstripped nib files to support a localization workflow, you should either use ibtool's --strip command to strip nib files after localizing, or temporarily revert the "Flatten Compiled XIB Files" and "Strip NIB Files" build settings to build nib files compatible with previous iOS releases." I tried to use that config. setting, but still wouldn't load the NIB. So I did a kinda hacky solution, but appears to work:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some docs, it became clear that iOS prior 3.2 won't load NIBs from Xcode 4.2, so I ended up building the project with Xcode 3.2 and copied these NIBs to the package created with Xcode 4.2 under the DerivedData directory, the good part is I still can debug the app with Xcode 4.2, the bad part is, this is kinda hacky, but I hadn't choice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I second Emanuel's answer above. After many weeks of pulling my hair out I came up with this solution: 
[Build universal app for iOS 3.0 using Xcode 4.3.x - NSKeyedUnarchiver Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961631/build-universal-app-for-ios-3-0-using-xcode-4-3-x-nskeyedunarchiver-exception/10074943#10074943)